# ASP.NET MVC: pass parameter from a date input and refresh the current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a date input, get the data from it and refresh the page with the selected date. 
Currently, I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group higher col-sm-4">
    <div>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" id="date-input">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var dateInput = document.getElementById('date-input');
    dateInput.oninput = function () {
        window.location.href = UpdateQueryString("dateInput", dateInput.value)
    };
</script>
```

The controller signature looks like that:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string dateInput)
```

It reloads the page but it seems that the Index isn't getting the value from the date input.
I've tried searching a solution on a similar topic but I still can't fix my problem.

I'm wondering if there's another better way to proceed to get the same result too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try to add the `[FromUri]` attribute to your `string dateInput`

Comment: What is the value of `url` in your script? (and why is your parameter a `string` when your wanting a `DateTime`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've changed the parameter to a DateTime. For example, the value of url is "?dateInput=2018-02-15".

Comment: That will work fine.

Comment: It's working, thanks for your help @StephenMuecke and IvanMladenov